# How to combine two subplots in one tkinter window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, data-visualization

I would like to display **two matplotlib plots** below each other **in one tkinter window**. I have needed two different codes so far. How can I combine the codes in one? I have created the desired result with powerpoint below. I have already tried it with subplot, unfortunately without success: plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(20,10)) **and** plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20,10))

[image: Subplot in one tkinter window]
My first code:

```
# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Library 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk 
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Carwash Array
Carwash_km = np.array([1,4,500,1500,2800,2960,2700,5,2000,2000,3100,4000,4150,4150])
Carwash_cost = np.array([5,1000,1000,2100,3000,3150,3150,20,50,600,3500,3800,3960,3700])

# Fuel Array
Fuel_km = np.array([2,5,600,2600,3900,3970,3800,6,3000,3000,4200,5000,5260,5260])
Fuel_cost = np.array([6,2000,2000,3200,4000,4260,4260,30,60,700,4600,4900,4070,4800])

# Maintenance Array
Maintenance_km = np.array([0,3,400,400,1700,1850,1600,4,1000,1000,2000,3000,3040,3040])
Maintenance_cost = np.array([4,500,500,1000,2000,2040,2040,10,40,500,2400,2700,2850,2600])

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Main
Vis = tk.Tk()
Vis.title("Main") # titel

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,5), facecolor = "white")


Plot_Carwash_cost = plt.bar(Carwash_km, Carwash_cost, 
                             bottom=0, 
                             color="#BDD7EE", 
                             ec="black", 
                             width=100, 
                             label="Carwash_cost")


Plot_Carwash_cost2 = plt.bar(Maintenance_km, -Maintenance_cost, 
                                 bottom=-0, 
                                 color="#C5E0B4",
                                 ec="black",
                                 width=100, 
                                 label="Maintenance_cost")

Plot_Fuel = plt.scatter(Fuel_km, Fuel_cost, 
                             marker="^", 
                             s=150, 
                             color="#C00000", 
                             edgecolors="black", 
                             zorder=3, 
                             label="Fuel_cost")

ax.spines["bottom"].set_position("zero")
ax.spines["top"].set_color("none")
ax.spines["right"].set_color("none")
ax.spines["left"].set_color("none")
ax.tick_params(axis="x", length=20)

_, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_xlim(-15, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax+10) # legend
ax.text(xmax, -5, "km", ha="right", va="top", size=14)
plt.legend(ncol=5, loc="upper left")
plt.tight_layout() 

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Canvas, Toolbar
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=Vis)
canvas.draw() # TK-Drawingarea
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, Vis)
toolbar.update()

Vis.mainloop()
```

My second code:

```
# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk 
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# 1 Array
Beg1 = np.array([1,4,500,1500,2800,2960,2700,5,2000,2000,3100,4000,4150,4150])
End1 = np.array([2,5,600,2600,3900,3970,3800,6,3000,3000,4200,5000,5260,5260])

# 2 Array
Beg2 = np.array([5,1000,1000,2100,3000,3150,3150,20,50,600,3500,3800,3960,3700])
End2 = np.array([6,2000,2000,3200,4000,4260,4260,30,60,700,4600,4900,4070,4800])

# 3 Array
Beg3 = np.array([0,3,400,400,1700,1850,1600,4,1000,1000,2000,3000,3040,3040])
End3 = np.array([4,500,500,1000,2000,2040,2040,10,40,500,2400,2700,2850,2600])

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# detail
Vis2 = tk.Tk()
Vis2.title("detail") # titel

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20,10), facecolor = "white")

Plot_1 = plt.barh(len(Beg1)+np.arange(len(Beg2)),  End2-Beg2+500, 
                   left=Beg2,
                   height=0.9,
                   color='red',
                   alpha=0.5)

Plot_2 = plt.barh(range(len(Beg1)),  End1-Beg1, 
                    left=Beg1,
                    height=0.9,
                    color='#BDD7EE')

Plot_3 = plt.barh(len(Beg1)+len(Beg2)+np.arange(len(Beg3)),  End3-Beg3+500, 
                   left=Beg3,
                   height=0.9,
                   color="#C5E0B4")

plt.tight_layout()

# ___________________________________________________________________________
# Canvas, Toolbar
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = Vis2)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, Vis2)
toolbar.update()

Vis2.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#excuse me

#in

class GraphFrame(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):

    super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

    self.fig = Figure()
```

## I think the correct sintax is :

class GraphFrame(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):

    super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

    self.fig = plt.figure()
```

## Am I right?

Comment: No, this is not correct. And this does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to create two `Frame` widget, and have your `FigureCanvasTkAgg` master set to each `Frame`.

```
...
frame1 = tk.Frame(Vis)
frame2 = tk.Frame(Vis)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()

...
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = frame1)
...
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = frame2)
...

Vis.mainloop()
```

A better way is to create a class which inherits from `Frame` and handles the creation of `Figure` and `NavigationToolBar`. Depending on your need, it could be something like this:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure #use Figure instead of pyplot if you are embedding into tkinter

class GraphFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
```

Then you can easily create new plotting areas under the same root window `Vis`:

```
Vis = tk.Tk()

graph1 = GraphFrame(Vis)
graph1.pack()
graph1.ax.bar(Carwash_km, Carwash_cost, ...)
graph1.ax.bar(Maintenance_km, -Maintenance_cost, ...)
graph1.ax.scatter(Fuel_km, Fuel_cost, ...)

graph2 = GraphFrame(Vis)
graph2.pack()
graph2.ax.barh(...)
graph2.ax.barh(...)
graph2.ax.barh(...)

Vis.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it.